# Multiple transitions on multiple d3 paths

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am not an experienced programmer so apologies from the start if this question is obvious to some of you.

I am trying to draw 4 concentric circles in D3/SVG than when clicked will increase in radius and move in the y axis simultaneously.

I've managed to get one arc to change radius (please see the jfiddle) but ideally I'd like to get

1. all the arcs changing from `var radiusSmall` to `var radiusLarge` (I've tried a for loop on different arc classes but this didn't work)
2. all the arcs to move 300px in the y-axis. I've put in my best guess on lines 78 to 82 of the js JSfiddle but it doesn't seem to be firing.

I know there is some complication about scheduling multiple transitions in d3 but I think there may be more than one error stopping me do this.

Your help is much appreciated!

JSfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/benws1/3xk9qgqe/3/

```
function zoom(d) {

    if (zoomToggle === 0) {

        d3.selectAll(".arc1")
            .transition().duration(500).ease("cubic")
            .attrTween("d", function (d) {

            var intRadIn = d3.interpolate(d.innerRadius, radiusLarge[2]);
            var intRadOut = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, radiusLarge[3]);

            return function (t) {
                innerRad = intRadIn(t);
                outerRad = intRadOut(t);
                return arc(d);
            };
        });

        d3.selectAll(".arcGroup")
            .transition().duration(500).ease("cubic")
            .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + xOffset + "," + yOffset + 300 + ")";
        });

        zoomToggle = 1;

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more class to arc paths as shown below.

```
arcGroup.append("path")
    .datum({
       innerRadius: innerRad,
       outerRadius: outerRad,
       startAngle: minAngArc,
       endAngle: maxAngArc
    })
    .attr("class", "arc_path arc" + i) //added arc_path class
    .attr("d", arc)
    .attr("fill", "#3f4749")
    .on("click", zoom);
```

Now, apply transition to each path in zoom function using each function

```
d3.selectAll(".arc_path")
    .each(function(d,i){
        d3.select(this)
            .transition().duration(500)
            .ease("cubic")
            .attrTween("d", function (d) {
                var intRadIn = d3.interpolate(d.innerRadius, radiusLarge[i+1]);
                var intRadOut = d3.interpolate(d.outerRadius, radiusLarge[i+2]);
                return function (t) {
                    innerRad = intRadIn(t);
                    outerRad = intRadOut(t);
                    return arc(d);
                };
            });
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xk9qgqe/5/) Hope this helps.

**Update**

You forgot to argGroup class to the g element.

```
var arcGroup = chartArea.append("g")
    .attr("class","arcGroup")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + xOffset + "," + yOffset + ")");
```

Add a parenthesis to y Offset like this `(yOffset + 300)` or else it will do a string concatenation.

```
d3.selectAll(".arcGroup")
        .transition().duration(500).ease("cubic")
        .attr("transform", function (d) {
            return "translate(" + xOffset + "," + (yOffset + 300) + ")";
        });
```

Comment: Thanks Gilsha. That's a neat way of grouping items in a class that I hadn't seen but it doesn't solve part II - the simultaneous translation. Do you know a way of doing this?

Comment: @HobbyHacker Your code for y axis transformation is 80% right, but has a few problems. Updated the answer and fiddle.